# How to use "tags" with Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this "Select2" dropdownmenu which get populated from ajax and php.
The script I have here is allowing one choice to be made, and passed into a html element. I'd like to use this code with "tags". I've tried but can't figure out how to fetch all selected values? How do I send what is selected?

**HTML**

```
//form
<input type='hidden' class='col-md-4' id='choose_usr_email' name='choose_usr_email' required>
//Snap up whats chosed
<input type='text' id='chosen_usr_email' name='chosen_usr_email'>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var chosenUsr = $('#choose_usr_email');
$("#choose_usr_email").select2({
    tags: true,
    placeholder: "Välj användare..",
    ajax: {
    url: "time.php",
    dataType: 'json',
        //search term
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
            q: term, // search term
            page: page
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
        return { results: data};
        }
    } // Ajax Call
}); // Select2

// Start Change
$(chosenUsr).change(function() {
    var usrId = $(chosenUsr).select2('data').id;
    var usrEmail = $(chosenUsr).select2('data').text;
    var timeNr = $(chosenUsr).select2('data').timenr;
    var usrfName = $(chosenUsr).select2('data').usrfname;
 
    $('#chosen_usr_id').val(usrId);
    $('#chosen_usr_email').val(usrEmail);
    $('#chosen_usr_time_nr').val(timeNr);
    $('#chosen_usr_fname').val(usrfName);
  
  }); //Change
}); //Document Ready
```

Comment: push the array while selecting values and send element by element in ajax (single 'post')

Comment: I dont know how to do that!

Comment: push your userId,userEmail... in array then that array to another array which will have list of users inside. then post it in ajax. some google-ing will help you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With [select2 v.4.0](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html) you can use *multiple* dropdown.

Set name as `choose_usr_email[]`, so that it will create array of tags on submit.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" id="tagForm">
    <select multiple="true" name="choose_usr_email[]" id="choose_usr_email" class="form-control select2">
        <!-- if tags are loaded over AJAX, no need for <option> elments -->
    </select>
    <!-- more form elements ... -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
$('#choose_usr_email').select2({
    tags: true,
    // automatically creates tag when user hit space or comma:
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
    ajax: {
        url: "time.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        //search term
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term, // search term
                page: page
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            return { results: data};
        }
    }
});

// handle form submission:
$('#tagForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        // PHP file where you send selected values:
        url      : "file.php",
        // if you want to use $_POST in PHP, uncomment the line below:
        // type  : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        // serialize the form:
        data     : $('#tagForm').serialize(),
        success  : function(response){
            // handle server response ...
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP** *(file where you send selected values)*

```
<?php

    // If 'type' is not specified in AJAX, use $_GET
    // check if 'choose_usr_email' exists in AJAX request
    if(isset($_GET['choose_usr_email']){
        // if exists, loop through the values:
        foreach($_GET['choose_usr_email'] as $key => $value){
            // do something with each $value (each submitted tag)
        }
    }

?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qq3fc689/)

---

### For Select2 < v.4.0

`$('#choose_usr_email').val();` returns each selected tag *id* (if specified) or *text*, separated by coma (1,2,3,...).

```
$('#tagForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        // PHP file where you send selected values:
        url      : "file.php",
        // if you want to use $_POST in PHP, uncomment the line below:
        // type  : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        // request data, split input field value by comma:
        data     : {
            choose_usr_email : $('#choose_usr_email').val().split(',')
        },
        success  : function(response){
            // handle server response ...
        }
    });
});
```

Then you can process the AJAX request the same way as in previous PHP example.

Comment: When i run this example in my project i got: Uncaught Error: Option 'tags' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.

Comment: What version of select2 are you using? Try [**select2 v4.0**](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html)

Comment: I load 3.5 because i have it on my main menu, (4.0 didnt support "hidden" input) but after it i also load 4.0 so, it should be the latest loaded... but i still got the same error...

Comment: I need to take a break! Thank you so much for your support. I will try your updated example later on...

Comment: @d00rman , you could use something like in my **EDIT** section

Comment: In your solution, tags appear as new options, is possible to not display any option and still be able to add tags?